API Management: the policy is not correctly recognizing the syntax of the expressions
I want to apply this policy in one of the APIs to redirect the token it receives to the API https://obw.stdn.com.pe/api/mf/v3/ami/authorize
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" 
                      failed-validation-httpcode="401" 
                      failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
            <openid-config url="https://uatidpbsp.b2clogin.com/uatidpbsp.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_LOGIN_OOBB/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
            <audiences>
                <audience>01c396bf-e852-b396-d0a7e4d0d373</audience>
                <audience>c2ef0c9f-98f1-920e-44fb99c98026</audience>
            </audiences>
            <issuers>
                <issuer>https://uatidpbsp.b2clogin.com/a359g4c43-4228-563k5-89b6/v2.0/</issuer>
            </issuers>
        </validate-jwt>

        <!-- Send the request to the external endpoint with the token -->
        <send-request mode="new">
            <set-url>https://obw.stdn.com.pe/api/mf/v3/ami/authorize</set-url>
            <set-method>POST</set-method>
            
            <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
                <value>Bearer @(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization", ""))</value>
            </set-header>
            
            <set-header name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" exists-action="override">
                <value>e75ee8762a842htf96e36ba5f9z8c275</value>
            </set-header>
            
            <set-body>
                <value>{}</value>
            </set-body>
        </send-request>

        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>

I get the following error:

Some of the policy expressions may not have the correct parentheses or braces format. Please ensure that all policy expressions are in the correct format @() or @{}, in order to avoid any issues.

When I try to save the policy, I get a syntax error.

The send request policy requires two modifications:

a response varibale is required
<send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="responseExternal">

the curly braces of the body-value have to be removed
<set-body><value /></set-body>


The complete policy:
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
            <openid-config url="https://uatidpbsp.b2clogin.com/uatidpbsp.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_LOGIN_OOBB/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
            <audiences>
                <audience>01c396bf-e852-b396-d0a7e4d0d373</audience>
                <audience>c2ef0c9f-98f1-920e-44fb99c98026</audience>
            </audiences>
            <issuers>
                <issuer>https://uatidpbsp.b2clogin.com/a359g4c43-4228-563k5-89b6/v2.0/</issuer>
            </issuers>
        </validate-jwt>
        <!-- Send the request to the external endpoint with the token -->
        <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="responseExternal">
            <set-url>https://obw.stdn.com.pe/api/mf/v3/ami/authorize</set-url>
            <set-method>POST</set-method>
            <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
                <value>Bearer @(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization", ""))</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-header name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" exists-action="override">
                <value>e75ee8762a842htf96e36ba5f9z8c275</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-body>
                <value />
            </set-body>
        </send-request>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>

